# Replace "\\" with "\" in a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, backslash

I still don't get how to do this. I saw many posts regarding this, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have a string called "a\\b". The result I need is "a\b". How is this done?

I have a text file which has a database connection string pointing to an instance called - Server\DbInstance

My aim is to do a string replace in the text file -- replace "Server\DbInstance" with another value, say "10.11.12.13, 1200".

So I have:

```
stringToBeReplaced = @"Server\DbInstance";
newString = @"10.11.12.13, 1200";
```

This is where the problem starts. My stringToBeReplaced will always be "Server\\DbInstance", and when I search for this string in my text file, the search fails, as the text file doesn't have a string "Server\\DbInstance"; instead it has only "Server\DbInstance". So how do change "Server\\DbInstance" to "Server\DbInstance"?

Comment: do you need a string that has the value "a\b" or writes "a\b" when its printed?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I suspect your string already *actually* only contains a single backslash, but you're looking at it in the debugger which is escaping it for you into a form which would be valid as a regular string literal in C#.

If print it out in the console, or in a message box, does it show with two backslashes or one?

If you *actually* want to replace a double backslash with a single one, it's easy to do so:

```
text = text.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

... but my guess is that the original doesn't contain a double backslash anyway. If this doesn't help, please give more details.

EDIT: In response to the edited question, your `stringToBeReplaced` only has a single backslash in. Really. Wherever you're seeing two backslashes, that viewer is escaping it. The string itself doesn't have two backslashes. Examine `stringToBeReplaced.Length` and count the characters.

Comment: Its still not working for me :(
I have updated the question with my current scenario.

Comment: @user762730: The string you have shown only has a single backslash in. You haven't been clear about how you're seeing it with two backslashes, but it *really* only has one. Are you still looking in the debugger?

Comment: Ok. If it's really just a single slash, then why is this string not getting replaced in the text file??? Do I need to do something else to replace these kind of things??

Comment: @user762730: You haven't shown us the code you're using to perform the replacement, so we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: Solved the issue...
The problem was with the Replace I was doing.
I was performing a Regex.Replace. Instead, I should have used string.Replace method...

    Regex.Replace(stringToBeReplaced, @"\\", @"\") doesn't work..
    stringToBeReplaced.Replace(@"\\", @"\") WORKS...!!!!

Comment: @user762730: If `stringToBeReplaced` is really declared as shown in your sample code, that doesn't make sense - because the code you've got *really only has one backslash*. Perhaps it isn't really representative of your real code?

Answer (score 19):

in case someone got stuck with this and none of the answers above worked, below is what worked for me.  Hope it helps.

```
var oldString = "\\r|\\n";

// None of these worked for me
// var newString = oldString(@"\\", @"\");
// var newString = oldString.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
// var newString = oldString.Replace("\\u5b89", "\u5b89");
// var newString = Regex.Replace(oldString , @"\\", @"\");

// This is what worked
var newString = Regex.Unescape(oldString);
// newString is now "\r|\n"
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried the procedures of your posts but with no success.

This is what I get from debugger:
[image]

Original string that I save into sqlite database was `b\r\na` .. when I read them, I get `b\\r\\na` (length in debugger is 6: `"b" "\" "\r" "\" "\n" "a"`) then I try replace this string and I get string with length 6 again (you can see in picture above).

I run this short script in my test form with only one text box:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "b\\r\\na";
        string y = x.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
        this.textBox.Text = y + "\r\n\r\nLength: " + y.Length.ToString();
    }
```

and I get this in text box (so, no new line characters between "b" and "a":

```
b\r\na

Length: 6
```

What can I do with this string to unescape backslash? (I expect new line between "b" and "a".)

**Solution:**

OK, this is not possible to do with standard replace, because of `\r` and `\n` is one character. Is possible to replace part of string character by character but not possible to replace "half part" of one character. So, I must replace any special character separatelly, like this:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ...
    string z = x.Replace(@"\r\n", Environment.NewLine);
    ...
```

This produce correct result for me:

```
b
a
```

Comment: `"my\\r\\nstring".Replace(@"\r\n", "\r\n")` works. Notice only the text to replace has the `@` infront of it

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem until I read Jon Skeet's answer about the debugger displaying a single backslash with a double backslash even though the string may have a single backslash. I was not aware of that.
So I changed my code from

```
text2 = text1.Replace(@"\\", @"/");
```

to

```
text2 = text1.Replace(@"\", @"/");
```

and that solved the problem. 
Note: I'm interfacing and R.Net which uses single forward slashes in path strings.

Answer (score 2):

Regex.Unescape(string) method converts any escaped characters in the input string.

The Unescape method performs one of the following two transformations:

1. It reverses the transformation performed by the Escape method by
   removing the escape character ("\") from each character escaped by
   the method. These include the \, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $, ., #,
   and white space characters. In addition, the Unescape method
   unescapes the closing bracket (]) and closing brace (}) characters.
2. It replaces the hexadecimal values in verbatim string literals with
   the actual printable characters. For example, it replaces @"\x07"
   with "\a", or @"\x0A" with "\n". It converts to supported escape
   characters such as \a, \b, \e, \n, \r, \f, \t, \v, and alphanumeric
   characters.

```
string str = @"a\\b\\c";
var output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str);
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the issue in the question, adding an explanation will help other users understand the solution and improve the quality.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
var newstring = @"a\\b".Replace(@"\\",@"\");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = @"a\\b";
a = a.Replace(@"\\",@"\");
```

should work.
Remember that in the watch Visual STudio show the "\" escaped so you see "\" in place of a single one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a replace in your string like

```
Str.Replace(@"\\",@"\");
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution works but I chose the implementation below. I ALSO realized that I was referencing the wrong path. Be sure to check the path you're using.

```
 @"C:\Users\me\path"
```