# Replace method c# not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to replace double backslash for simple one but it does not work. Here an image:

[image]

I still wondering why. I saw post like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp) and it worked for them.
Suggestions?

Update

**Sorry i made a mistake, its a single backslashes just i spelled wrong**
the code to replace is

```
string clear_patch = path.Replace(@"\\","\");
```

Comment: Your string doesn't contain double backslashes. Click on the magnifying glass and you will see.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, its a single backslashes just i spelled wrong

Comment: `user2195741` I would suggest reading up on `Escape Characters` as well as what a `Literal` means when using `@` symbol this will help you out tremendously

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need a txt file's value.

Comment: Do you actually believe there can be double backslashes in the method input parameter or are you just confused by the string visualiser escaping backslashes by doubling them?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Im reading <a href="http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma#Escaping-whatfor2">article</a> and now im understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is working. `\\` is not escaped whilst inspecting during debugging. Try printing the value to a console window or the webpage.

Edit* You appear to be confused.

Your path doesn't actually contain any double slashes `\\`, it just looks that way because the single slashes are escaped when viewing the string during debugging. Consider reading up on [Escape sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx).

If you want to escape **single** slashes then don't use a verbatim string literal in your replace e.g. `string.Replace("\\", "-")` which would replace all single slashes in the path with a hyphen `-` though I'm not sure why you would want to do this? Note that this will still show the path as having `\\` slashes in it whilst inspecting during debugging. Printing to a console window would read:

`C:-dev-vsprojects-VerificaionDeFirmas-VerificaionDeFirmas-verificaciondefirmas.txt`

Comment: It can't be working because a path does not contain double `\\` characters.

Comment: @Aphelion - The debugger automatically escapes backslashes by adding an extra "\" character.

Comment: @keyboardP I know but @'\\' will search for 2 of those characters. I assume as it is a path, the actual path does NOT contain double characters. Then why use the replace?

Comment: @Aphelion - That's true but that doesn't mean the code isn't working, it just means it's not doing anything worthwhile. I thought you meant the code isn't working because the debugger is showing two backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

The watch window is showing you the escaped string.  So when it shows `\\` the string only contains `\`.

Your replace is trying to replace `\\` because you are using the literal indicator `@`.

Change the replace code to:

```
string clear_path = path.Replace("\\", "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `"\\"`, not `@"\\"` as this looks for 2 `\` characters.

Note that the visualizer always shows the `\\` notation for `\` actual characters.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do:

```
string clear_path = path.Replace(@"\","-");
```

The representation in the debugger shows `\\` but that means escape char and `\`

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro - You fixed it in the edit by adding the "@" but you just edited it and removed it again. You need to escape the "\" either with the verbatim symbol (@) or using "\\".

Comment: @keyboardP No idea why this was reverted back. It's there again

Answer (score 0):

You should not double escape it, either you do:

```
string clear_path = path.Replace("\\","-")
```

or

```
string clear_path = path.Replace(@"\","-")
```