# C# MVC, reading carriage returns from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to put a list of delimiters in a web.config file, one of the delimiters is a carriage return - `\r\n`. 
The web.config entry looks like this -

```
<add key="Separators" value=" |,|;|\r\n"/>
```

I am trying to read in the list using a call like the following -

```
string[] MySeparators = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ConfigSettings.PartNumberSeparators].Split('|');
```

The list is being read, but the carriage return ends up containing extra back slashes and looks like this - `\\r\\n`

Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Note that `\r` in Web.Config is just a string with 2 characters `\` and `r` - there is no escaping unlike in C#.... "Why slashes shown as double slashes when I look at string in debug view" is mandatory daily question on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813454/replace-method-c-sharp-not-working-as-expected/15813489#15813489

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using XML entities `&#10;` and `&#13;`.  Provided that the .NET configuration system supports resolving these entities, then these should appear as `\r\n` at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

First, you forgot the | between \n and \r

Try writing a var like

```
>var test = "\";
```

this will give you an error, options are:

```
>var test = "\\";

>var test = @"\";
```

Try the second one

Comment: Hey Thiag0coelho, "\r\n" together represent a carriage return. I did not forget to put a "|" between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape`, this way:

```
string[] MySeparators = Regex.Unescape(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ConfigSettings.PartNumberSeparators]).Split('|');
```