# Replacing a specific character with string.replace()

Tags: c#, string, replace, backslash, slash

I'd like to replace all occurences of `/` to `\` . i used this snippet:

```
_url =  _url.Replace("/",@"\");
```

but it replaces `/` to `\\`.
[image: im]

Why this happens? How can i modify the snippet to get a good result

Comment: No it works correctly, Just use the debugger's magnifier icon to see the exact string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string most likely already contains a single backslash!

```
I suspect your string already actually only contains a single backslash, 
but you're looking at it in the debugger which is escaping it for you into
a form which would be valid as a regular string literal in C#.
```

quoted Jon Skeet from: [Replace "\\" with "\" in a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you attempted to verify correct operation in the debugger. Visual Studio's debugger tips escape backslash characters, so if you see `\\` in the tooltip then the string actually contains only 1 backslash. Click the magnifying glass icon at the end of the tooltip in the debugger to bring up a dialog containing the unescaped text.

**Edit**: This applies to the watch windows as well, including the part about the magnifying glass at the end.