# To remove double quotes in string array

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have a string array which holds values like "1,2,3" i want to remove the double quotes and display as 1,2,3.pls help me to do this.

```
string[] Stocks = StockDetails.ToArray();
string s = string.Join(",", Stocks);
```

Comment: Just Replace("\"","")

Comment: I guess you're looking in to the debugger. It will show including the quotes but actually there's not.

Comment: Most likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp which talks about strings shown by debugger... Need sample that explains where `"` are shown (i.e. with result of `Console.WriteLine(s);`) to understand if it is duplicate of "you are observing values in debugger" or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having string in this format

```
string str = "\"1,2,3\"";
```

..then you can simply remove the double quotation marks using Replace method on string.

```
str = str.Replace("\"", "");
```

..this will replace the double quotation from your string, and will return the simple text that is not a double quotes.

*More* I don't think strings are like this, you're having a look at the actual value of the variable string you're having. When you will use it, it will give you the actual `1, 2, 3` but however, use the above code to remove the quotation .

Comment: I tried this but it does not remove double quotes my o/p should be 1,2,3 .My actual o/p is "1,2,3"

Comment: Good! Then there is no proble, read the _More_ section of my answer. It has a little bit clarification that this value will not effect your actual value. Don't worry, when you display it, it will be in good format that you want it to be. This is just the value inside the string variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var listOfStrings = StockDetails.Select(s => s.Replace("\"", string.Empty))
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: It is not working can we convert to integer to avoid double quotes?

Comment: @user3930037 - Where are you checking the values? if its in a debugger click on the magnifying glass icon to see the real value.