# C# I´m trying to put a single backslash but even using @"\" he puts \\

Tags: c#

```
string url = @"..\" + row.Field<String>(1).Replace("photo",@"photo\");
url.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

i´m trying to put a single backslash but c# put that as \\

Comment: Why do you think it puts \\? Tip: the debugger will always show \ characters escaped with another \ but the string doesn't actually contain two of them.

Comment: Right but if you output to console there will be only one backslash

Comment: Also you can use Text Visualizer to see the exact text while debugging.

Comment: This question is asked thousand times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like the following?

string url = @"..\" + row.Field(1).Replace("photo",@"photo\");
url = url.Replace(@"\", @"\");

i,e add "url = " assigning.

Comment: `url = url.Replace(@"\", @"\");` I'm not sure that actually does anything, since you are replacing a string with the same string...