# Why this double "\\" string replacement is not working in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am pretty new in `C#` and I am finding the following difficulties with a string replace operation.

I have the following situation:

```
string utenteActiveDirectory = utente.UserId.Split('|')[1].Replace("\\", @"\");
```

where `utente.UserId.Split('|')[1]` contains the following string: `domain\\username`.

I have to replace the double `\\` with the single `\` character. But trying with the previous line of code it is not working and I still have `domain\\username` instead the expected `domain\username` result.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: `"\\"` and `@"\"` are the same thing. I think you want `@"\\", @"\"`

Comment: Does the string *really* contain ``\\``, or is that just what the debugger is telling you? It will "helpfully" show special characters as their escape sequences, when the string actually contains only the single character ``\`` (and so no replacing is actually necessary).

Comment: That code replaces a single backslash with a single backslash.  Do avoid getting confused by the way the debugger displays strings.  It favors showing them the way you'd write them in your program.  So doubles the backslashes.  Have another look-see by clicking the spyglass icon.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right, it was the debugger !!! If you put it as answer I will accept it !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace "\\" with "\" in a string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482360/replace-with-in-a-string-in-c-sharp) . This occurs so many times I knew we had to have a duplicate *somewhere*. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
string utenteActiveDirectory = utente.UserId.Split('|')[1].Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

The reason for this is \ is an escape character, so all you are actually doing in your original code is replacing \ with \

Comment: I am still obtaining the same \\ after the replacement

Comment: How do you verify that you still have double backslashes?